# Prevent installation of Security Scan/Anti-virus software?

Tags: windows, anti-virus

Is there a way, in Windows, to prevent the user from installing all of the 'free' security scan or anti-virus software that seems to come bundled with so much free software these days? We provide anti-virus software for our users, but they often install software which adds another AV program, which slows the system down pretty badly.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would be not letting them install software at all, just so you know exactly what's going on your systems.

There's a lot worse out there that could find it's way in with an install!

Answer (score 0):

If it's "fake" AV software, using spybot's immunize feature and SpywareBlaster will prevent some cases of installation. Both are essentially [killbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killbit) solutions.

Another solution could be not allowing users to install anything--give them a power user (or lesser account) and lock things down via group policy.